# Como acessar o postgres de uma imagem docker?

Tags: docker, postgresql-10

Saudação, acabei de criar uma imagem docker do banco de dados PostgreSQL com algumas configurações adicionais como mostra no comando abaixo:

```
docker run -p 15432:15432 --name kwandb -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MorangocomUva1 -e POSTGRES_DB=kwan -d postgres:10.5-alpine
```

O banco está rodando como podem ver na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero executar o comando `CREATE DATABASE guru99;` no banco de dados PostgreSQL, mas se trata de uma imagem do docker, como irei encontra na imagem do banco de dados para cria a base de dados?

Eu sei fazer isso quando o banco de dados está instalado localmente no meu sistema operacional, mas aqui se trata de uma imagem.

Comment: O que significa `-p 15432:15432` do seu comando?

Comment: significa que estou rodando o banco de dados na porta 15432

Comment: Eu só estou precisando entrar no terminal do container do banco de dados postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Opção 1:

Você pode utilizar uma sessão interativa usando o [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/):

> Executa um comando em um container em execução.
>
> Uso:
>   docker exec [OPCOES] CONTAINER COMANDO [ARGUMENTO...]

Para o seu caso, basta rodar o seguinte:

```
docker exec -it kwandb psql -U postgres
```

Isso iniciará um terminal interativo no seu container em execução, rodando o `psql` com o usuário que você especificou.

---

### Opção 2:

Se você tem o `psql` disponível no seu host, você pode utilizá-lo para conectar-se ao container na porta que você publicou. Porém você deve primeiro corrigir o `docker run` para direcionar a porta corretamente ( *0.0.0.0:15432->**5432**/tcp )*:

```
docker run -p 15432:5432 --name kwandb -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MorangocomUva1 -e POSTGRES_DB=kwan -d postgres:10.5-alpine
```

Feito isso, basta se conectar ao container utilizando a porta exportada:

`psql -h localhost -p 15432 -U postgres`

A senha do usuário será perguntada. Caso deseje pular esse passo interativo, defina a variável [`PGPASSWORD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-envars.html) junto com o comando:

`PGPASSWORD='MorangocomUva1' psql -h localhost -p 15432 -U postgres`

*Obs: O uso da variável de ambiente não é boa prática de segurança. Para uso em ambientes de produção, considere a autenticação via [arquivo `~/.pgpass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-pgpass.html)*

Comment: Ou conectar pela porta mapeada: localhost:15432

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sugestão adicionada à resposta